# Python code produces error `ORA-00917: missing comma', but no comma is missing. What is wrong?

Tags: python, oracle

I wrote Python code but I am getting this error:

> Error  ORA-00917: missing comma

but there is no missing comma; what is wrong?

```
sTableName = "IRM_PREP_EPS_NRTRDEFLAT"

# build the SQL insert statement    
sql_str = "INSERT INTO " + sTableName + " (ID,EPSDV_ERROR_FILE,EPSDV_ERROR_FILE_CREATION,EPSDV_RECORD_NUMBER,EPSDV_ERROR_CODE,EPSDV_ERROR_MESSAGE,"
sql_str = sql_str + "EPSDV_CURRENT_AREA,EPSDV_PREVIOUS_AREA,EPSDV_EQUIPMENT,EPSDV_PORTAL,EPSDV_PLAN,EPSDV_OPERATION,EPSDV_EXTERNAL_FILENAME,"
sql_str = sql_str + "EPSDV_LAST_MODIFIED_BY,EPSDV_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,RECORD_TYPE,SPECIFICATION_VERSION_NUMBER,RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER,SENDER,"
sql_str = sql_str + "RECIPIENT,SEQUENCE_NUMBER,FILE_AVAILABLE_TIMESTAMP,UTC_TIMEOFFSET_FAT,IMSI,IMEI,CALL_EVENT_START_TIMESTAMP,UTC_TIMEOFFSET_CET,"
sql_str = sql_str + "CALL_EVENT_DURATION,CAUSE_FOR_TERMINATION,TELE_SERVICE_CODE,BEARER_SERVICE_CODE,SUPPLEMENTARY_SERVICE_CODE,DIALLED_DIGITS,"
sql_str = sql_str + "CONNECTED_NUMBER,THIRD_PARTY_NUMBER,CALLING_NUMBER,RECENTITY_ID,CALL_REFERENCE,ACCESS_POINT_NAME_NI,ACCESS_POINT_NAME_OI,"
sql_str = sql_str + "DATA_VOLUME_INCOMING,DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING,SGSN_ADDRESS,GGSN_ADDRESS,CHARGING_ID,CHARGE_AMOUNT,SERVING_NETWORK,MSISDN,"
sql_str = sql_str + "LOCATION_AREA,CELL_ID,FILLER) VALUES ("

sql_str = sql_str + ID + ',' + EPSDV_ERROR_FILE + ',' + EPSDV_ERROR_FILE_CREATION + ',' + EPSDV_RECORD_NUMBER + ',' + EPSDV_ERROR_CODE + ',' + EPSDV_ERROR_MESSAGE
sql_str = sql_str + ',' + EPSDV_CURRENT_AREA + ',' + EPSDV_PREVIOUS_AREA + ',' + EPSDV_EQUIPMENT + ',' + EPSDV_PORTAL + ',' + EPSDV_PLAN + ',' 
sql_str = sql_str + EPSDV_OPERATION + ',' + EPSDV_EXTERNAL_FILENAME + ',' + EPSDV_LAST_MODIFIED_BY + ',' + EPSDV_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE + ','
sql_str = sql_str + RECORD_TYPE + ',' + SPECIFICATION_VERSION_NUMBER + ',' + RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER + ',' + SENDER + ',' + RECIPIENT + ','
sql_str = sql_str + SEQUENCE_NUMBER + ',' + FILE_AVAILABLE_TIMESTAMP + ',' + UTC_TIMEOFFSET_FAT + ',' + IMSI + ',' + IMEI + ',' 
sql_str = sql_str + CALL_EVENT_START_TIMESTAMP + ',' + UTC_TIMEOFFSET_CET + ',' + CALL_EVENT_DURATION + ',' + CAUSE_FOR_TERMINATION + ',' 
sql_str = sql_str + TELE_SERVICE_CODE + ',' + BEARER_SERVICE_CODE + ',' + SUPPLEMENTARY_SERVICE_CODE + ',' + DIALLED_DIGITS + ',' + CONNECTED_NUMBER
sql_str = sql_str + ',' + THIRD_PARTY_NUMBER + ',' + CALLING_NUMBER + ',' + RECENTITY_ID + ',' + CALL_REFERENCE + ',' + ACCESS_POINT_NAME_NI
sql_str = sql_str + ',' + ACCESS_POINT_NAME_OI + ',' + DATA_VOLUME_INCOMING + ',' + DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING + ',' + SGSN_ADDRESS + ','
sql_str = sql_str + GGSN_ADDRESS + ',' + CHARGING_ID + ',' + CHARGE_AMOUNT + ',' + SERVING_NETWORK + ',' + MSISDN + ',' + LOCATION_AREA + ','
sql_str = sql_str + CELL_ID + ',' + FILLER + ')'
```

Comment: The easiest way to debug such a problem is to print out the statement and test it in whatever SQL tool you commonly use.  Here you're essentially asking us to spot a typo you made...

Comment: you have to read about [variables binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html)

Comment: ORA- means the error is coming from Oracle, not Python. That said, you should really learn some Python, as this is a totally horrible way to build up an SQL string. (Hint: triple quotes, and `','.join()`.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your error position, it might be caused by several reasons, for example if your strings are not enclosed in `'` quotes. It's a very wrong way to pass variables to sql.

Pobably more robust and correct in terms of bind variables usage (cornerstone of oracle SQL best practices) is to write your statement as (didn't test it):

```
sTableName = 'IRM_PREP_EPS_NRTRDEFLAT'
fields_str = ("ID,EPSDV_ERROR_FILE,EPSDV_ERROR_FILE_CREATION,EPSDV_RECORD_NUMBER,"
              "EPSDV_ERROR_CODE,EPSDV_ERROR_MESSAGE,EPSDV_CURRENT_AREA,"
              "EPSDV_PREVIOUS_AREA,EPSDV_EQUIPMENT,EPSDV_PORTAL,EPSDV_PLAN,"
              "EPSDV_OPERATION,EPSDV_EXTERNAL_FILENAME,EPSDV_LAST_MODIFIED_BY,"
              "EPSDV_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,RECORD_TYPE,SPECIFICATION_VERSION_NUMBER,"
              "RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER,SENDER,RECIPIENT,SEQUENCE_NUMBER,"
              "FILE_AVAILABLE_TIMESTAMP,UTC_TIMEOFFSET_FAT,IMSI,IMEI,"
              "CALL_EVENT_START_TIMESTAMP,UTC_TIMEOFFSET_CET,CALL_EVENT_DURATION,"
              "CAUSE_FOR_TERMINATION,TELE_SERVICE_CODE,BEARER_SERVICE_CODE,"
              "SUPPLEMENTARY_SERVICE_CODE,DIALLED_DIGITS,CONNECTED_NUMBER,"
              "THIRD_PARTY_NUMBER,CALLING_NUMBER,RECENTITY_ID,CALL_REFERENCE,"
              "ACCESS_POINT_NAME_NI,ACCESS_POINT_NAME_OI,DATA_VOLUME_INCOMING,"
              "DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING,SGSN_ADDRESS,GGSN_ADDRESS,CHARGING_ID,"
              "CHARGE_AMOUNT,SERVING_NETWORK,MSISDN,LOCATION_AREA,CELL_ID,FILLER")
fields = fields_str.split(',')
vars = ','.join(map(':{}'.format, fields)))
sql = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES({})'.format(sTableName,
           fields_str, vars)
values = {f: locals()[f] for f in fields}
cur.execute(sql, values)
```